# Управление потоком «с выдачей кредитов»

Tags: сеть

Задание на моделирование многосегментной сети TCP. Что такое механизм управления потоком  «с выдачей кредитов»? Еще в задании указано: "Кредит выдается исходя из требования сохранения размера окна W." Это как-то связано с методом "Скользящее окно"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ответ:

Предотвращение переполнения буфера приёмника на основе системы "кредитов" на канальном уровне (передача не начнётся пока в приёмном буфере не будет достаточно места).

Отправитель после отправки данных вычитает единицу из буферного кредита данного получателя; если кредит обнулился, то дальнейшая передача этому получателю приостанавливается; получатель после получения данных посылает отправителю подтверждение получения кадра (ACK); отправитель, получив кредит, добавляет единицу к буферному кредиту; если кредит до этого был равен нулю, то возобновляется приостановленная передача